# Can RenderScript code (i.e. standalone rs file) be independently compiled outside ADT setup?

Tags: android, renderscript

I wish to compile my single rs file, into bytecode, independently outside ADT (Eclipse) setup. Is there a script available to do that?

Comment: Have you tried Android's ant build script? http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: Yes. Essentially I would like to build a single rs file and not the whole project. Something like javac command that converts .java file to .class file.

Comment: You might want to explain for what purpose you just want a single rs file as ant builds should be handling in project changes and  the build process usual creates the Java stubs needed by the rest of Android. If you wanted to know which part of the SDK is building it look at <SDK>/build-tools/x.x.y/llvm-rs-cc

Comment: llvm-rs-cc is the right start point however can't get the syntax right for using it in order to create .bc from my input .rs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what works for me on my mac. running from the sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/ directory:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` ./llvm-rs-cc -I renderscript/include/ -I renderscript/clang-include/ -emit-bc -o <output dir> <RS input>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It did the job for me too on Windows. Thanks again!

Comment: I couldn't locate the llvm-rs-cc in the built-android(i.e. containing 'out' folder) source directory.

Answer (score 0):

The AOSP uses the transform-renderscripts-to-java-and-bc macro in definitions.mk to compile rs files.  The macro uses llvm-rs-cc to build a renderscript bytecode file.

The ADT bundle has it in sdk/build-tools/18.1.X/llvm-rs-cc

The AOSP builds llvm-rs-cc and puts it in $(OUT)/host/linux-x86/bin/llvm-rs-cc

But how are you going to run the functions in the renderscript bytecode file?  Best is a java container. See $AOSP/packages/wallpapers/PhaseBeam for an example of java/rs bindings.

I guess you COULD do an NDK interface but I would have no idea which libraries to link.

Comment: Ha!  I just saw that Kitkat has a renderscript C++ interface in the NDK.  So as they say: "...so if you've been waiting to use RenderScript from your native code, give it a try."  I correct myself.